# Using subfig package with bmcart class breaks caption formatting

Tags: formatting

I am writing a paper for a journal and have to use the `bmcart` class of the BioMed Central template found [here](http://www.biomedcentral.com/authors/tex) ([direct link to ZIP file](http://media.biomedcentral.com/content/production/bmc_article-tex.zip)).

I use subfigures, but as soon as I load the `subfig` package, all figure and subfigure captions become misformatted, i.e., they are shown in a different font and they overflow the bounding box that this template draws around every figure. As a minimal example, it suffices to load the `subfig` package in the file `bmc_article.tex` provided as template.

My question: how do I insert subfigures without breaking the formatting?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried the sample article and found that loading `subfig` with the proper option works:

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

Adding this to the sample file

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \subfloat{X}\quad\subfloat{Y}
  \caption{\csentence{Sample figure title.}
      Figure legend text.}
 \end{figure}
```

gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: Do you know why the default behaviour is to change the caption formatting? I would assume that a sensible default would be to have minimum interference with the class.

Comment: @nedim The fact is that the `caption` package is incompatible with the class, so the result is unpredictable; with `caption=false` the `subfig` package doesn't load also `caption` like it does if the option is not set.